# HTTPS issue when using http-server application in nodejs

Tags: node.js, https, dns, web-hosting, a-records

Hello I am definitely new to HTTPS so please bear with me. In order to run the nodejs application, http-server, I use this command on my webserver:

```
http-server -p 80 -S
```

The -p flag specifies the port and then the -S flag specifies that I will be using the https protocol. I am able to access the website just fine by physically going to the web server's address like:

```
https://123.456.78.90:80
```

However when I try to access the site from my domain:

```
example.com
```

or even:

```
https://example.com
```

I get a connection refused error in the browser. This perplexes me as I have created A records to redirect the domain to the ip address with digital ocean, along with using their nameservers. This whole process works flawlessly when I start up an instance of http-server in normal http mode like this:

```
http-server -p 80
```

Any help is MUCH appreciated as I haven't been able to find much on the topic. Thanks internet people.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a free ports. The port 80 is currently used for http connections.

```
http-server -p 9090
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still no avail. I am still able to access the https version of the site if I manually enter the address, I just can't get my domain to point to that location correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Wow figured it out. I needed to specify the port 443 when starting the http-server for https to work properly.